# How to resize github images inside github flavored markdown (i.e. issues / PRs)?

Tags: github

Is there any quick and easy way to change the size of an image pasted into a github issue?

#### Example

[Here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16319829/79087218-ef769280-7d81-11ea-93d6-a81ea2a7474e.png)'s a random github image. If it's used in a github issue like so

```
![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16319829/79087218-ef769280-7d81-11ea-93d6-a81ea2a7474e.png)
```

It will display largish.

How can we easily make it medium or small as simply as possible (preferably by only editing the url or adding something to it)?

#### What I've tried

I tried both of these (suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/uupaa/f77d2bcf4dc7a294d109)), but neither work:

```
![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16319829/79087218-ef769280-7d81-11ea-93d6-a81ea2a7474e.png | width=100)

![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16319829/79087218-ef769280-7d81-11ea-93d6-a81ea2a7474e.png = 250x250)
```

#### Note

- I'm not sure how it works, but stack overflow have a very convenient convention of adding an `l` (large), `s` (small), `m` (medium) to end of an image url to change the size (I also tried this in github but no luck)

Answer (score 3):

This works for me in issues:

```
<img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16319829/79087218-ef769280-7d81-11ea-93d6-a81ea2a7474e.png" data-canonical-src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16319829/79087218-ef769280-7d81-11ea-93d6-a81ea2a7474e.png" width="200" height="200" />
```